# How to pass a variable an id variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

Okay, I have this in my Codeigniter controller:

```
public function post($id) {
$data['query'] = $this->blog_model->get_post($id);
$data['comments'] = $this->blog_model->get_post_comment($id);
$data['post_id']=$id;
$data['total_comments'] = $this->blog_model->total_comments($id);
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));
//validation rules for post function

$this->form_validation->set_rules('commenter','Name','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Your email','required'|'valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('comment','Comment','required');

if($this->blog_model->get_post($id))
{
foreach($this->blog_model->get_post($id) as $row)
{
//set page title
$data['title'] = $row->entry_name;
}
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
//if validation runs FALSE
$this->load->view('blog/post',$data);
}
else
{
//if valid
        $name = $this->input->post('comment_name');
        $email = strtolower($this->input->post('comment_email'));
        $comment = $this->input->post('comment_body');
        $post_id = $this->input->post('entry_id');

        $this->blog_model->add_new_comment($post_id,$name,$email,$comment);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '1 new comment added!');
        redirect('post/'.$id);
 }
 }
 else
 show_404();
 }
```

In my post view I have this:

```
echo form_open('blog/post'.$id);
```

I want to pass a `$id` variable which I enter in the URL, to the post view for comment form. How do I pass the `$id` variable to the view?

Comment: It's been a while for me & CI, but don't you just add it to the $data array before loading the view?

Comment: Also note that you are missing a `/` at in the form_open call: `form_open('blog/post/'.$id);` (and maybe even the path should start with one as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing **id** in your data array, here:

```
$data['post_id']=$id;
```

In your view instead of `$id` just use `$post_id`:

```
echo form_open('blog/post'.$post_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->load->view('your post view',array('id'=>$the_id_here))
```

then in your view , use the $id variable.

Comment: when i pass it like this: $this->load->view('blog/post',array('$data','$id'))
it says undefined variable?

Comment: you're using wrong syntax try : $this->load->view('blog/post',array('id'=>'$id')) , I suppose you have a folder in your views called 'blog' , inside there is a view called post ?

Comment: yes i have a view folder called blog and it has a post inside, i tried it but still undefined variable?

Comment: how to pass $data and $id together

Comment: can you post all the error text here ? and use this : $this->load->view('blog/post',array('id'=>$post_id))

Comment: if you want to pass multiple variables to the view use this : $this->load->view('blog/post',array('id'=>$post_id,'anotherVariabl'=>$value,'thirdVariable'=>$thirdValue)) and so on